# Obfuscate links (for SEO purpose)

Tags: php, links, seo, optimization

Link obfuscation is a more and more common topic in order to improve SEO by masking the non-important links to provide more weight to others.

I'm looking for an efficient way to obfuscate links in Wordpress, directly in the source code obviously, for example by adding a special class to my links.

It must turn the `<a>` element into something else like a `<span>`, with no more visible *href* attribute nor any actual URL, so that robots cannot see any link.

It must be done **before** rendering the source code, not overridden in JavaScript.

Example :

`<a href="https://example.com">Hello</a>`

turns into :

`<span data-o="CRYPTEDLINK">Hello</span>`

then some JS allows click on the element to redirect to the original link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own system that allows me to obfuscate any link easily.

Add the following code to your child theme's *functions.php* file, then just add the class "obfuscate" to any  element to obfuscate its link by replacing it with a  element with no readable link.

Also be sure to edit styles above, or delet them and style the "akn-obf-link" class in your own CSS file, so that it looks like a link to the visitor.

```
/*************************************************************************************\
|* Links obuscation - add class "obfuscate" to any <a> element to obfuscate its link *|
\*************************************************************************************/

// Add this code to your child theme's functions.php file, then just add the class "obfuscate" to any <a> element to obfuscate its link by replacing it with a <span> element with no readable link.
// The obfuscated elements inherits the original <a> element's classes, along with a "akn-obf-link" class, so you might need to add CSS to style the "akn-obf-link" class so that it looks like a link to the visitor, maybe at least to add a cursor:pointer.
// On right click, the obfuscated link will be wrapped with a proper <a> element with the "akn-deobf-link" for a brief moment, so that a proper context menu appears, you can remove that behaviour by setting the "deobfucate_on_right_click" option to false in the code bellow.

// Edit 2022-04-05 - modified regex to allow for html elements and new lines into the <a> element, modified callback so the obfuscated element inherits the original link's classes, modified JS to add mousewheel click and right click options.

add_action('wp_loaded', 'buffer_start');
function buffer_start() {
    ob_start('akn_ofbuscate_buffer');
}
add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');
function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
function akn_ofbuscate_buffer($buffer) {
    $result = preg_replace_callback('#<a[^>]+(href=(\"|\')([^\"\']*)(\'|\")[^>]+class=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*obfuscate[^\'\"]*(\"|\')|class=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*obfuscate[^\'\"]*(\"|\')[^>]+href=(\"|\')([^\"\']*)(\'|\"))[^>]*>(.+(?!<a))<\/a>#imUs', function($matches) {
        preg_match('#<a[^>]+class=[\"|\\\']([^\\\'\"]+)[\"|\\\']#imUs',$matches[0],$matches_classes);
        $classes = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',str_replace('obfuscate','',$matches_classes[1])));
        return '<span class="akn-obf-link'.($classes?' '.$classes:'').'" data-o="'.base64_encode($matches[3]?:$matches[10]).'" data-b="'.((strpos(strtolower($matches[0]),'_blank')!==false)?'1':'0').'">'.$matches[12].'</span>';
    }, $buffer);
    return $result;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'akn_ofbuscate_footer_js');
function akn_ofbuscate_footer_js() {
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                // options you can change
                var deobfuscate_on_right_click = true;
                // function to open link on click
                function akn_ofbuscate_clicked($el,force_blank) {
                    if (typeof(force_blank)=='undefined')
                        var force_blank = false;
                    var link = atob($el.data('o'));
                    var _blank = $el.data('b');
                    if (_blank || force_blank)
                        window.open(link);
                    else
                        location.href = link;
                }
                // trigger link opening on click
                $(document).on('click','.akn-obf-link',function() {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    if (!$el.closest('.akn-deobf-link').length)
                        akn_ofbuscate_clicked($el);
                });
                // trigger link openin in new tab on mousewheel click
                $(document).on('mousedown','.akn-obf-link',function(e) {
                    if (e.which==2) {
                        var $el = $(this);
                        if (!$el.closest('.akn-deobf-link').length) {
                            akn_ofbuscate_clicked($el,true);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                // deobfuscate link on right click so the context menu is a legit menu with link options
                $(document).on('contextmenu','.akn-obf-link',function(e) {
                    if (deobfuscate_on_right_click) {
                        var $el = $(this);
                        if (!$el.closest('.akn-deobf-link').length) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            var link = atob($el.data('o'));
                            var _blank = $el.data('b');
                            $el.wrap('<a class="akn-deobf-link" href="'+link+'"'+(_blank?' target="_BLANK"':'')+'></a>').parent().trigger('contextmenu');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $el.unwrap();
                            },10);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

I'm also sharing the code on this Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/cXEBSVFn

Consider checking the link just in case I updated the code on it and forgot to update it here